# How to link two CSS file (one for styling the webpage and other for styling a countdown timer) with one single HTML file?

Tags: html, css

I have two files of CSS, one is for styling webpage and the other is for styling my countdown timer. I have tried with the following but it uses to follow only one CSS file at a time (depending on what I have linked last). How can I use both files at the same time?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Background.css">
<script type="text/css" src="CountDown.css">
```

Comment: I suggest trying to understand what each of the tags do by reading some documentation; This will help you in your web dev journey as understanding what you are doing is an important part.

Answer (score 1):

Look,  means you are linking a 'stylesheet' named 'Background.css' to your html file.

means you are adding some JS file/ script to your html file.

You have messed up between the 'script' tag and 'link' tag.

So, here you are trying to add two style/css files. that means two link tag with two different file name. Then, the code will be-

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Background.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Countdown.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two style files like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Background.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Countdown.css">
```